# Discord.js - saving data to mongodb

Tags: mongodb, discord.js

I've never had this problem before but for some reason, I've had it now, I just need another set of eyes to look at the code and see if I missed something.
I'm trying to save a token to a MongoDB database but I keep getting this error message (node:14756) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: ReferenceError: Cannot access 'Token' before initialization

This is the actual command

```
     let tokens = makeid(5)
     message.channel.send(`${member}\'s token for ${bottype} has been created! The token is (${tokens}), Their userID is  ${userID}.`)
     Token.save()
    } else {
        return message.reply("You do not have the correct permissions to perform this action.")
    }
    const Token = new token({
        _id: mongoose.Types.ObjectId(),
        dname: member,
        dtoken: tokens,
        bottype: bottype,
        userid: userid  
    })
```

and  this is the model file

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const tokenSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  _id: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
  dname: String,
  dtoken: String,
  bottype: String,
  userid: String
});

module.exports = mongoose.model("Token", tokenSchema)
```

I've been staring at this for a while and I've probably missed something.

Comment: The error explains it all, you are trying to save `Token` before even creating it.

Comment: Are you sure your `Token` file is being required somewhere before you run the piece of code where you use it to write something?

Comment: If I put the Token schema before the Token.save() it gives me this error `(node:1852) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: ReferenceError: token is not defined`

Comment: I found my issue, I forgot to require the model file in my command file... I hate myself.